# Check how many changes were made by UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have infinite loop in which I update whole values from one column with select-generated column. I want to break the loop when number of changes in update is 0. Update returns number of rows so what I need is to compare before update and after update column.

Comment: "I have inifinte loop." There's your first problem.

Comment: Looking for @@RowCount ?

Comment: @@RowCount will give me number of rows. Infinite loop is needed, but I have also safety-break parameter

Comment: Pseudo-code? Is your loop exit condition that the affected rows by the update are 0?

Comment: what's `number of changes in update`

Comment: I have column1 and column2. I update column1 width column2 values. Number of changes is number of rows which were changed (update '1' to '1' is not a change)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this :-

```
    WHILE(1)
    BEGIN 
    -- Some logic here ---
    UPDATE HumanResources.Employee 
    SET JobTitle = N'Executive'
    WHERE NationalIDNumber = 123456789
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BREAK 

    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@@ROWCOUNT` to get the number of rows that were affected by `UPDATE`. You can get the number of rows that were actually different by providing the `UPDATE` clause with a `WHERE` clause which excludes the rows that do not need to change. For example:

```
UPDATE Tbl1
SET col1 = col2
WHERE col1 != col2

IF ( @@RowCount == 0) BREAK
```